# How to maintain referential integrity when parents tables keys are changed?

Tags: c#

I have created a C# app that makes a clone copy from an MS Access database and migrates the data to another DB server, but that will require changing the primary keys.  What is the best way to maintain the referential integrity to the child tables when the parent tables keys are changed?

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 3):

You may already know this but your primary key column values should not be changing, much, if at all. However, that aside, you don't mention what database you are using. But with SQL Server, you can set up FK's to do what is called a cascading update. This means that if a PK value changes, all FK rows in child tables will have the value changed as well.

The following is an article describing this:  `http://blogs.techrepublic.com.com/datacenter/?p=128`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have autoIncrement set as the datatype on the PK field of an Access table and you want equivalent functionality in your new db.

Import the Access tables into destination tables with numeric, not auto-increment, data types.  Then add your RI back between parent and child tables.  Then edit your PK field to auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

I did end up using composite primary keys since each time the app makes a clone copy it is a "snapshot" of the entire dataset.  I've therefore added a columne called "Revision" and set each table's primary key to Pk = OID + REVISION.

For the child table it should reference the parent table by their primary key, which means the foreign key will also be composite.  How do you achieve that relationship in Access?  What I have done is in Access 2007 go to "Database Tools" -> "Relationship" and there edit the relationship so that it displays the following:

(parent Oid) 1 <--- many (child parentKey), (parent Revision) 1 <--- many (child Revision)

Please tell me is this is the way to do it.  Or if someone can tell me how to achieve that using SQL commands I'll try that too.

Thanks,